# I want to know how to make the date automatically change the year only in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to know how to make the date automatically change the year only

For example, if I have this date in the database 9/21/2020
I want the year to change every year, for example, we are now 2022. The date in the database is 9/21/2022

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you can do something like

```
while (myDate.Year < DateTime.Now.Year)
{
    myDate = myDate.AddYears(1);
}
```

Comment: This nicely handles leap years